# While loop in CasperJS?

Tags: ajax, while-loop, web-scraping, casperjs

I've got a website with Ajax-loaded content. The content is showed in tabs, 20 items par page, with an Ajax link to load the 20 following items.

I'd like to run some tests as :
"As long as there is a link to the next page, click it, then ... [do something]", 
then proceed to the next page (loop)

I can't know for sure how many pages I'll have to go through.

Is there a simple way to achieve this ?
(ie something like a While loop in CasperJS)

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are multiple answers to this type of question here: [CasperJS loop or iterate through multiple web pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23384963/1816580). Hint: you need recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

[casperjs-goto](https://github.com/yotsumoto/casperjs-goto)

Hope it helps