# Parsing multiple pages of website and count total items

Tags: javascript, casperjs

My script simply gathers the number of reports on a page, then goes to the next page and does the same. The goal is to get the total number of reports across multiple pages.

**UPDATED**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["./lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"],
    // verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('LOG: ' + msg);
});

casper.on('page.error', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR' );
});

var reportCount, newReportCount, reportPages;

casper.start("reports.html", function() {

    reportPages = this.evaluate(function() {
        return $('#table2 tbody tr td').children('a').length -1;
  });

  //first page of reports
  reportCount = this.evaluate(function() {
      return $('#table1 tbody').first().children('tr').length;
  });

  this.echo('initial count: ' + reportCount);
  this.echo('pages: ' + reportPages);

  //check if more than 1 page and add report count
  if (reportPages > 1) {
    newReportCount = this.thenOpen('reports2.html', function(){
        var newCount = this.evaluate(function(count) {
            add = count + $('#table1 tbody').first().children('tr').length;
            // console.log('new count inside: ' + add);
            return add;
        }, reportCount);
        console.log(newCount); //this shows correct new value 32
    });
    console.log(newReportCount); //this shows [object Casper]

    neoReportCount = this.thenOpen('reports3.html', function(count){
        console.log(newReportCount); //this shows [object Casper]
        //do the same count
    }, newReportCount);
  }

casper.run();
```

Here is the output in console

```
Pages: 3
First count: 15
[object Casper], currently at file:///**/reports.html
32
[object Casper], currently at file:///**/reports3.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you use `casper.thenOpenAndEvaluate()` which has the word `then` in it. It means that this function is asynchronous and it returns the `casper` object to enable a builder/promise pattern. So you cannot return anything from a function like this. Since it is asynchronous, it will be executed after the current step ends, which is after `console.log(newCount);`.

You would need to split the function, for example like this:

```
//check if more than 1 page and add report count
if (reportPages > 1) {
  var newCount;
  this.thenOpen('reports2.html', function(count){
    newCount = this.evaluate(function(count){
      add = count + $('#table1 tbody').first().children('tr').length;
      console.log('new count inside: ' + add);
      return add;
    }, reportCount);
    console.log(newCount);
  }).thenOpen('reports3.html', function(count){
    newCount += this.evaluate(function(count){
      add = count + $('#table1 tbody').first().children('tr').length;
      console.log('new count inside: ' + add);
      return add;
    }, reportCount);
    console.log(newCount);
  }).then(function(){
    console.log(newCount);
  });
}
```

It seems like you want to loop over multiple pages. This is usually done recursively, because CasperJS is asynchronous and you don't know beforehand how many pages you need to open. I suggest you look at this question for some examples: [CasperJS loop or iterate through multiple web pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384963/casperjs-loop-or-iterate-through-multiple-web-pages)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response. I modified the code with the suggestion you made for separating open and evaluate. I am still unable to figure out how to the new count value outside the .thenOpen function. The log of newReportCount looks like it's executed before the value is returned, so that's why I get the object? I think I'll need some sort of callback, but how would I implement that in casper?

Comment: @JeffreyTu Please read my answer carefully. You cannot return something from `casper.thenOpen` because it is asynchronous like all the other `then*` and `wait*` functions. You probably want that `newCount` will be a global variable so you can add to it?